# Problem with Facebook like button in Firefox

Tags: facebook

When I click a Facebook *like* button in Firefox, I see the following behaviour:

1. Blank popup window opens
2. Window closes very quickly
3. In-page like button updates (implying that I like the page)
4. Blank popup window opens again
5. In-page like button reverts to the 'not liking' state
6. Goto 2

It is not happening in Internet Explorer. Is there a popup setting or an add-on I can use to fix this problem?

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Firefox v.3.6.13 on Mac.

Anyone know of an answer for this? I've eliminated everything else on my page except for the script that Facebook generates for me from their Facebook Like page for developers.

Comment: gosh this is what I've been looking for 6months!
I had same problem with Firefox 3.6.13 on winXP.
Thanks dude you saved my life.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in *[Facebook Like button + Firefox + neverending popups](http://www.addthis.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=27647)*.

You have to allow third-party cookies in Firefox. The Facebook *like* button script laughs at your futile attempt to keep your privacy safe. Yikes!